# Align iframe in jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to display and iframe into a jquery ui dialog. This iframe needs to be resized according to the desired user's dialog size. The dialog should occupie all the dialog's space but the title (top) nor the resize button (bottom right).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("<div id ='container'><iframe src='http://www.google.com'></iframe></div>").dialog({modal:true,title:"Title",width:800,height:600});
});
```

​
Any idea? I'm becoming mad with the css widths and heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/xyctR/18/

Iframe will populate with jsfiddle and rest you can see the behavior.

Hope this helps,

Following code will suffice your need i.e. "needs to be resized according to the desired user's dialog size. The dialog should occupie all the dialog's space but the title (top) nor the resize button"

**Code**

```
function showDialog(url){
   var iframe = $('<iframe id="modalIframeId" width="100%" height="100%" src='+url+' marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title">Your browser does not support</iframe>')
    .on('load', function() {
        console.log('loaded');
    });

    $("#divId")
        .append('<div id="loading">Loading....</div>')
        .append(iframe)
        .dialog({modal:true,title:"Title",width:800,height:600});
}

showDialog('http://jsfiddle.net');

​**image**
```

[image]

Comment: The 2nd or 3rd time I do that the screen locks and I need to refresh. Even the F5 doesn¡t work. The Loading does not disappear. The resize button is not visisble.

Comment: Hiya @JordiPlanadecursach hmm interesting I am on osx Lion safacri, tried but my screen is fine, umm is it something else can you flick me more detail in fiddle, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is ok for you.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("<div id ='container' style='padding:0px; margin:0px; overflow:hidden;'><iframe height=100% width=100% style='width:100%; height:100%;padding:0px; margin:0px;' frameborder=0 src='http://www.stack.com'></iframe></div>").dialog({modal:true,title:"Title",width:400,height:400});
});
```

**UPDATE**
Changed code due to possible padding-margin problems.

Comment: Hello, I see a double vertical scroll bar (in FF). Do you see it as well ?

Comment: I change the overflow prop. Try it again.

Comment: same, and the resize button is not visible. I'm wondering if the jQuery dialog is a good component.

Comment: sorry, I fixed it. Problem was I wrote `none` in `overflow` property of `container`, changed it with `hidden`.